# Horizontal animated swipe menu for Android

Tags: java, android, animation, menu, swipe

What is the best way to build this horizontal swipe menu in Java for Android?

[image]

The biggest challenges for me:

1. First item must be in center
2. During swipe the image and orange button are of items are animated

Thank you!

Comment: Could you add more details in it?

Comment: I have tried to make this menu using RecyclerView but I am not able the make the first item be in center (it is on the left). Also I am not sure how can I animate the image and button during the swipe as it is on the GIF